# RHEL 6.2 hangs at startup screen after forced reboot

Tags: rhel6

I had to force a hardware reboot due to some CPU hungry application. It now hangs at the start-up screen right after the progress circle completes.

I have no way to see what it is doing (checking the FS or something) but when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>, a s/w reboot occurs in 5 seconds.

How can I see the regular Linux start-up log instead of the splash screen and at least understand what it is doing.

Comment: use the dmesg your boot.log to troubleshoot the booting problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boot your machine as you would normally and when prompted to, *Press any key to enter the menu* do so.

In the grub menu select the entry you want to boot then press `e`

Highlight the kernel line and press `e`

Navigate to the end of the line and remove `rhgb quiet` then press enter

Press `b` to boot your system.

You should now see the system messages as it boots.

Comment: The "escape" key normally switched to the boot-up message.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this would probably take me years to find out!

Comment: @AndreasM -- escape works, but as soon as the circle progress is done, it does not

Comment: @Iain Your solution make the system continue to boot up, but unfortunately the stuck later after starting atd service! Any addition?

Comment: Turns out that selinux cause the problem, just adding `selinux=0` to the end, and then pressing `b` make the system boot up.